# Getting this error - the IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize in

Tags: php, encryption

After going through a lot of encryption/decryption stuff by googling, I manage to build this piece of code. But, it showing following error which i can't able to figure out WHY it is happening.

ERROR : **Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize in /var/www/encrypt.php on line 16**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

class Cipher {
    private $securekey, $iv;
    function __construct($textkey) {
        $this->securekey = hash('sha256',$textkey,TRUE);
        //$this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32);
        $size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
    }

    function encrypt($input) {
        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $this->iv));
    }

    function decrypt($input) {
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $this->iv));
    }
}

$cipher = new Cipher('secret passphrase');

$encryptedtext = $cipher->encrypt("hide me");
echo "->encrypt = $encryptedtext<br />";

$decryptedtext = $cipher->decrypt($encryptedtext);
echo "->decrypt = $decryptedtext<br />";

var_dump($cipher);
```

If i comment following 2 lines from CONSTRUCTOR function..

```
$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
```

& uncomment this line..

```
$this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32);
```

It stopped showing error.

I can't able to identify what's i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Side note: `securekey` is a misnomer if you are just hashing a password. Google for PBKDF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the wrong algorithm name to `mcrypt_get_iv_size()`. You are passing `MCRYPT_CAST_256` when it should be `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`.

[CAST-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST-256) has a block size of 16 bytes whereas `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` specifies Rijndael with a 32 byte block size. That will be causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. you are right. I was using wrong algorithm. Actually, i'm trying to build one Encryption/Decryption library which will be used for encryption of user's personal data data like.. SSN, DOB & some financial information.

Can you give me some idea, is this CLASS is good to deal with those kind of info or i should use something else.